# Random Prime Methods by calling another method

Tags: java, random

I am having a difficult time trying to figure out this program. I have made a method to find out if the number entered is a prime number but now I have to write a method that that takes a positive int num as it's parameter and returns a random prime number in the range of [0, num-1]. I'm not sure if I am using the isPrime method correctly. Also I have to test this method by calling it in the main but I'm not sure as how to do that as well. Here is my code:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int num)
{
    for(int i = 2; i<= num-1;i++)
    {
        if (num % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }        
    }
    return true;
}

public static int randomPrime(int num)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int x = r.nextInt(num);

    for( int i = 0; i <= x; i++)
    {
        if(!isPrime(x))
        {
            num = x;
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: in your `randomPrime` method you're assigning `num = x`, and then you do nothing with that information. Instead, you probably want to build the list of all primes between 0 and num-1 first, and then to return "the" random prime, select a random index between 0 and list.size()-1 (inclusive) and return list.get(that_index)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an efficient way to do it. I would recommend you to construct an [Eratosthene sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) and then select a random item of it.

Here is how I would do it :

```
public static Random rd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

public static int randomPrime(int num) {
    Boolean[] sieve = new Boolean[num+1];
    sieve[0] = true;
    sieve[1] = true;
    for (int i=2 ; i<num.length ; i++)
       if (!sieve[i])
           for (int j = 2*i ; j<num.length ; j += i) 
                sieve[j] = true;

    List<Integer> primes = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i=0 ; i<sieve.length ; i++) 
        if (!sieve[i]) primes.add(i);

    return primes.isEmpty() ? -1 : primes.get(rd.nextInt(primes.size());
}
```

Comment: that's more of a comment than an answer. while inefficient, his isPrime method should work in terms of getting the right answer for the purposes of running `randomPrime`

Comment: my isPrime method works fine, I have to write it this way per instructions, I have to use a loop to see if the number generated is a prime or not. If it is then I exit and return the number, if it is not then I have to generate a new number. Also I'm not sure how to test this in the main.

Comment: I did not do any remark about `isPrime`, look carefully at my answer. I could propose a fix for `randomPrime` by moving `isPrime(x)` at the right place but even after the fix, it will always return 2 because it is the first prime between 0 and x (assuming that x >= 2, which this code does not even guarantees). The sieve is a much better idea.

Comment: Again, per instructions, I have to call the isPrime method in the randomPrime method, check to see if it is a prime, if not generate a new number and keep looping until a prime is generated.

Comment: @AmandaMerical Sometimes instructions are stupid and must be ignored. If you have solid reasons to ignore instructions of an assignment and can argue why your solution is better, it is fine to do it your way.

Comment: @Dici Perhaps not, if this assignment is part of a course which introduces the concepts of looping.

Comment: @Zéychin Then this would be a bad example

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking to see if `x` is prime in your `randomPrime` method, why are you calling `isPrime` on `0 <= i <= x`? You are checking if any number between (inclusive) 0 and x is prime. That is not what you want.

I think this should do the trick for you without a drastic change of algorithm. Note: This code may take an exceedingly long time to terminate based on your random number generator and seed value and is not actually guaranteed to terminate. (Consider the case where your random number generator only produces composite numbers.)

```
public static int randomPrime(int num)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int x = r.nextInt(num);

    while(!isPrime(x))
    {
        x = r.nextInt(num);
    }
    return x;
}
```

Update:

Test it with something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int N = 42;
    int x = randomPrime(N);
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindness. Do you have any advice for when I test this in the main method?

Comment: What kind of advice? I am not sure what you are asking for here.

Comment: Sorry, I have to test to make sure that the method works by calling it in the main method. My instructions say to call the isPrime method by randNumber as a parameter.